# How to flatten an array in a nested json in aws glue using pyspark?

Tags: arrays, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to flatten a JSON file to be able to load it into PostgreSQL all in AWS Glue. I am using PySpark. Using a crawler I crawl the S3 JSON and produce a table. I then use an ETL Glue script to:

- read the crawled table
- use the 'Relationalize' function to flatten the file
- convert the dynamic frame to a dataframe
- try to 'explode' the request.data field

Script so far:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_source_database, table_name = glue_source_table, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

df0 = Relationalize.apply(frame = datasource0, staging_path = glue_temp_storage, name = dfc_root_table_name, transformation_ctx = "dfc")

df1 = df0.select(dfc_root_table_name)

df2 = df1.toDF()

df2 = df1.select(explode(col('`request.data`')).alias("request_data"))

<then i write df1 to a PostgreSQL database which works fine>
```

Issues I face:

The 'Relationalize' function works well except the request.data field which becomes a bigint and therefore 'explode' doesn't work.

Explode cannot be done without using 'Relationalize' on the JSON first due to the structure of the data. Specifically the error is: "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`request.data`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not bigint"

If I try to make the dynamic frame a dataframe first then I get this issue: "py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.jdbc.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct..."

I tried to also upload a classifier so that the data would flatten in the crawl itself but AWS confirmed this wouldn't work.

The JSON format of the original file is as follows, that I an trying to normalise:

```
- field1
- field2
- {}
  - field3
  - {}
    - field4
    - field5
  - []
    - {}
      - field6
      - {}
        - field7
        - field8
        - {}
          - field9
          - {}
            - field10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Flatten nested df  
def flatten_df(nested_df): 
    for col in nested_df.columns:


    array_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == 'array']
    for col in array_cols:
        nested_df =nested_df.withColumn(col, F.explode_outer(nested_df[col]))

    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
    if len(nested_cols) == 0:
        return nested_df

    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']

    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                            [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])

    return flatten_df(flat_df)

df=flatten_df(df)
```

It will replace all dots with underscore. Note that it uses `explode_outer` and not `explode` to include Null value in case array itself is null. This function is available in `spark v2.4+` only.

Also remember, exploding array will add more duplicates and overall row size will increase. Flattening struct will increase column size. In short, your original df will explode horizontally and vertically. It may slow down processing data later.

Therefore my recommendation would be to identify feature related data and store only those data in postgresql and original json files in s3.

Comment: this works for most of my json files. But when the struct/array is NULL I get an error  *An error was encountered: 'No such struct field style in  list.ordered;*  How do I handle the null conditions?

Comment: is it possible to use the posexplode_outer function instead of explode_outer?

Comment: Nice one. The first line `for col in nested_df.columns:` needs to be removed

Comment: This will create duplicate records in the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Once you have rationalized the json column, you don't need to explode it. Relationalize transforms the nested JSON into key-value pairs at the outermost level of the JSON document. The transformed data maintains a list of the original keys from the nested JSON separated by periods.

**Example :**

Nested json :

```
{
    "player": {
        "username": "user1",
        "characteristics": {
            "race": "Human",
            "class": "Warlock",
            "subclass": "Dawnblade",
            "power": 300,
            "playercountry": "USA"
        },
        "arsenal": {
            "kinetic": {
                "name": "Sweet Business",
                "type": "Auto Rifle",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Kinetic"
            },
            "energy": {
                "name": "MIDA Mini-Tool",
                "type": "Submachine Gun",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Solar"
            },
            "power": {
                "name": "Play of the Game",
                "type": "Grenade Launcher",
                "power": 300,
                "element": "Arc"
            }
        },
        "armor": {
            "head": "Eye of Another World",
            "arms": "Philomath Gloves",
            "chest": "Philomath Robes",
            "leg": "Philomath Boots",
            "classitem": "Philomath Bond"
        },
        "location": {
            "map": "Titan",
            "waypoint": "The Rig"
        }
    }
}
```

Flattened out json after rationalize :

```
{
    "player.username": "user1",
    "player.characteristics.race": "Human",
    "player.characteristics.class": "Warlock",
    "player.characteristics.subclass": "Dawnblade",
    "player.characteristics.power": 300,
    "player.characteristics.playercountry": "USA",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.name": "Sweet Business",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.type": "Auto Rifle",
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.kinetic.element": "Kinetic",
    "player.arsenal.energy.name": "MIDA Mini-Tool",
    "player.arsenal.energy.type": "Submachine Gun",
    "player.arsenal.energy.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.energy.element": "Solar",
    "player.arsenal.power.name": "Play of the Game",
    "player.arsenal.power.type": "Grenade Launcher",
    "player.arsenal.power.power": 300,
    "player.arsenal.power.element": "Arc",
    "player.armor.head": "Eye of Another World",
    "player.armor.arms": "Philomath Gloves",
    "player.armor.chest": "Philomath Robes",
    "player.armor.leg": "Philomath Boots",
    "player.armor.classitem": "Philomath Bond",
    "player.location.map": "Titan",
    "player.location.waypoint": "The Rig"
}
```

Thus in your case, *request.data* is already a new column flattened out from request column and its type is interpreted as bigint by spark.

Reference : [Simplify/querying nested json with the aws glue relationalize transform](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/)

Comment: True, but the issue is there is an array in the JSON structure (request.data), that needs flattening out. Otherwise, it just returns bigint of 1 (i.e. omits the actual data inside) which is incorrect. rationalize works well otherwise.

Comment: @charlesperry, you are right. Relationalize works well only for the outermost level of the JSON and that should be explicit in the documentation. I am still trying to figure out the best way to relationalize a JSON file with 5 levels of nested arrays and structs.

Comment: @ruifgmonteiro did you manage to figure this one out. We're attempting to handle Rationalizing an object with nested arrays.

Comment: @Sigex we ended up using a different approach based on Spark SQL where we create a table based on the expected schema and from there on we use SQL to apply the needed transformations. This has been working well and it is a lot simpler than our initial approach which relied on recursively applying the transformations through the hierarchy levels. Bottom line, we decided not to put more effort into using glue libraries due to the lack of documentation and we see more benefit in using Spark libs as we could easily move to another platform without having to drastically change the code.